# MailChimp integration that allows users to select from multiple lists

Tags: plugins, customization, plugin-mailchimp

I'm integrating Mailchimp signup into a WP install and I have 2 questions.

1. What is the best way or best plugin to integrate mailchimp signup?
2. Is it possible to allow the user to select from multiple lists to be subscribed to.

I realize the latter is more closely related to MailChimp but I'm hoping that someone has an answer for that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Mailchimp Plugin for Wordpress does not allow user to select multiple lists. Infact Mailchimp discourage this practice.

Instead what they advocate is to create groups within the lists and then use segmenting while sending campaigns. These links might be useful

[MailChimp Documentation](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/is-it-possible-to-have-one-signup-form-that-submits-to-multiple-lists/)

[Google Groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/mailchimp-api-discuss/browse_thread/thread/ffd2544971da1138/67199b9f9fc5b1fb?pli=1)

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'll answer my own question. For those that did not know like myself, MailChimp has groups within a list. You can setup groups and your users can then select what groups they want to be added to. This essentially lets you have 1 master list and groups within it instead of managing multiple lists like most other mail programs would have you do.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp develops a plugin for wordpress......http://connect.mailchimp.com/

Comment: Do you know if that pluggin allows question 2) ?

Comment: From what i can tell it doesn't. It says you can create multiple instances of the plugin to allow users to signup for multiple lists. That's a no go since my client has 5+ lists and that would not look very nice on the site. I'd prefer something with checkboxes...maybe it will have to be custom written.